# How to remove fields from WooCommerce Customer Thank You Email (Customer Processing Order)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I need to remove the following from the Customer Processing Order email that WooCommerce sends customers once they have placed an order:

1. Payment Type
2. Price of items purchased
3. Everything that sits within the table below the items purchased, i.e. Total and Notes.

I've attached an image for a visual look at what needs ot be removed from the email:
items to be removed:
[image: items to be removed]

The file is found here: yourtheme/woocommerce/emails/customer-processing-order.php and it contains the code below but as you can see it's not a simple case of remove or comment out sections.:

```
<?php
/**
 * Customer processing order email
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/emails/customer-processing-order.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you
 * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
 * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
 * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
 * the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @package WooCommerce/Templates/Emails
 * @version 3.7.0
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}

/*
 * @hooked WC_Emails::email_header() Output the email header
 */
do_action( 'woocommerce_email_header', $email_heading, $email ); ?>

<?php /* translators: %s: Customer first name */ ?>
<p><?php printf( esc_html__( 'Hi %s,', 'woocommerce' ), esc_html( $order->get_billing_first_name() ) ); ?></p>
<?php /* translators: %s: Order number */ ?>
<p><?php printf( esc_html__( 'Just to let you know &mdash; we\'ve received your order #%s, and it is now being processed:', 'woocommerce' ), esc_html( $order->get_order_number() ) ); ?></p>

<?php

/*
 * @hooked WC_Emails::order_details() Shows the order details table.
 * @hooked WC_Structured_Data::generate_order_data() Generates structured data.
 * @hooked WC_Structured_Data::output_structured_data() Outputs structured data.
 * @since 2.5.0
 */
do_action( 'woocommerce_email_order_details', $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email );

/*
 * @hooked WC_Emails::order_meta() Shows order meta data.
 */
do_action( 'woocommerce_email_order_meta', $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email );

/*
 * @hooked WC_Emails::customer_details() Shows customer details
 * @hooked WC_Emails::email_address() Shows email address
 */
do_action( 'woocommerce_email_customer_details', $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email );

/**
 * Show user-defined additional content - this is set in each email's settings.
 */
if ( $additional_content ) {
    echo wp_kses_post( wpautop( wptexturize( $additional_content ) ) );
}

/*
 * @hooked WC_Emails::email_footer() Output the email footer
 */
do_action( 'woocommerce_email_footer', $email );
```

I've also used the following code in my functions.php file to remove the Subtotal and just below that, the Payment Method. But I still need help removing the other items.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_order_item_totals', 'adjust_woocommerce_get_order_item_totals' );

function adjust_woocommerce_get_order_item_totals( $totals ) {
  unset($totals['cart_subtotal']  );
  unset( $totals['payment_method'] );
  return $totals;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can custom the content using woocommerce_email_before_order_table hook

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_before_order_table', 'custom_process_table', 10, 4 );
function custom_process_table( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ) {
      // Your Custom Table goes here
}
```

you can also override the email template.
https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/templates/emails/email-order-details.php